# '!' : illegal operation on bound member function expression

Tags: c++, class, variables, object

this is my code for my coursework. i keep getting the same error.

'!' : illegal operation on bound member function

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>


#include "AMcore.h"
using namespace std;


int main (){


std::string filename1, filename2;

int plotPoint;

cout << "Amplitude Modulation Coursework" << endl;
cout << "Name: Mohammad Faizan Shah" << endl;
cout << "Student ID: 5526734 \n\n\n" << endl;

//AMcore obj1;

std::ifstream carrier(filename1);
cout << "Please enter the filename of the Carrier wave \n" << endl;
do{
    cin >> filename1;


    if (carrier.is_open)
    {
        cout << "file read succesfully... \n" << endl;
    }
    else if (!carrier.is_open)
    {
        cout << "file is not found!... Try carrier.txt...\n" << endl;

    }
} while (!carrier.is_open);
```

This is my AMcore file:
    //Function Definition
    #include 
    #include "AMcore.h"

```
AMcore::AMcore() {

std::string carrier  ;
std::string information ;

}            
AMcore::AMcore(string filename1, string filename2){
filename1 = carrier;
filename2 = information;

}

AMcore::~AMcore(){

}

string AMcore::getcarrier() const{
return carrier;


}
```

And finally my AMcore.h (header file)

```
   // Header -> Function Decleration

   #include <iostream>
   #include <string>

   using namespace std;

   #ifndef AMcore_h
   #define AMcore_h

    class AMcore{

    public:
    //defualt constructor
    string carrier;
    string information;
    AMcore();

    //overload constructor
    AMcore(string,string); 

    //destructor
    ~AMcore();

    //Accessor Functions
    string getcarrier() const;
    // returns name of txt file

    string getinformation() const;
    //returns name of txt file
```

Comment: You need `carrier.is_open()` in both cases. `is_open` is a function member, not a data member.

Comment: where exactly do i need this?

Comment: Whenever you call a function with no parameters, you need to add `()`

Comment: now i get this error.                                                                             .Error 1 error C3867: 'std::basic_ifstream<char,std::char_traits<char>>::is_open': function call missing argument list; use '&std::basic_ifstream<char,std::char_traits<char>>::is_open' to create a pointer to member e:\youtube cwk\youtube cwk\main.cpp 29

Comment: @FaizanFstahShah: Because to call a function, you have to say the round parentheses. Otherwise you're naming the function itself, not asking to *call* it.

Comment: Hi, i now enter carrier.txt which has been prompted in the main. However the IF statement executes the line where carrier.txt has not been opened. how do i actually get a resource file to open?

Comment: @KerrekSB ?? can you help?

Comment: @FaizanFstahShah: you'll need to _first_ read the file name, check that reading was successful, and then use the file name to create or open an `std::ifstream`.

Comment: @DietmarKühl and will it open up the files in my resources? can you scan my code and check which variable i need to rename???/

Comment: Where the file is opened depends on the implementation. I  have no idea what "resources" are. On the UNIX systems I'm normally working relative file names would be relative to the current working directory. I have no idea to what translates in your environment (partly because you didn't even state what environment you are on). ... and you'll fix your code yourself!

Comment: visual studios 2013 c++ @DietmarKühl

Comment: Its working directory for relative paths is the directory where the executable is created (e.g. "Debug"). You might want to try using an absolute path like `" c:\temp\test.txt"`.

Comment: @double backslashes will need to be used there (or forward slashes) if that string occurs in the program

Comment: `c:\\temp\\test.txt`

Comment: @M.M it appears as a unexpected token. Is there someway i can send you my visual basics folder?

Comment: No there isn't. Try to post a more coherent question.

Comment: @m.m okay so my code above follows a logical route. I now need the files i have in resources to read following the ifstatements i have in main. However once i run the code, it does not read the file a couts- file is not open